# Software to recover deleted files from Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, data-recovery

I need a good software to recover deleted files from Windows. Its specifications are -

1. It should be free.
2. It should recover maximum number of files with minimum time (I had used Piriform Recuva. It recovers maximum number of files, but it takes hours to recover all those.)
3. It should be a light software.

Which software will be good choice ?

Comment: GetDataBack Simple Data Recovery : https://www.runtime.org/

Comment: @senthilbp Hey, what this software is supposed to do ? Can you explain how to operate it and recover deleted files with it ?

Comment: You'll find lots of recommendations if you [search SuperUser for 'recovered deleted file'](http://superuser.com/search?q=recovered+deleted+file).

Comment: And whatever software you use, remember rule #1 when recovering deleted files: **Freeze the computer that you need to recover from**. Don't do anything with it (inclucing shutdown/startup) and disconnect it from the Internet to prevent automatic updates. Even installing the recovery software decreases your chance of succesful recovery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Recovery Software](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/251/file-recovery-software)

Comment: The speed of recovery depends more on the age/state of the hard drive and the number/condition of the files than on the software. I see nothing wrong with Recuva

Comment: File recovery is something that takes time because its *not* a trivial task. One does not simply walk into a ballgame and demand a pony.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) is a good application to recover deleted files(picture, video, music, documents and other type of files). We can operate it in 2 modes- Normal and Deep modes. Normal mode is fast and recovers less files. Deep mode is slow but it recovers almost every thing we deleted, out of which files in good or normal conditions can be recovered.