# Tool to recover part of a (Word) document

Tags: gratis, windows-8, data-recovery, microsoft-word

I know that [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) is a good program to use for recovering complete files that have been deleted (see [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11504/7730)), and I've even used it a few times, but I'm looking for something different.

A friend of mine was working on a long Microsoft word file earlier this week, and accidentally erased a large chunk of it. (He has since closed the file, and added new data to his disk, which doesn't help me much.....)
I know it doesn't look good, but I want to do my best to help him, if I could.

**What program can be used to recover a part of a file that has been deleted?**

I would prefer free software, if possible, but I wouldn't mind paying a couple of dollars for a very good program.

His computer is running Windows 8.1, 64 bit.

Comment: MS-Word often, (but not always), keeps history entries inside the documents whether you tell it to or not.  Copy the file, (not in word), to another name, then open the original and try "Edit->Undo"/Ctrl-Z or "Review->Show Changes".

Comment: @SteveBarnes Thanks for the recommendation! I'll definitely give it a shot....I was under the impression that Ctrl-Z ("Edit->Undo") does **not** work if the document has been closed....do you know something I don't?

Comment: Having mailed my CV to an agency and had them turn up with a copy showing the entire change history was a shock - certainly the older versions of word stored a lot of past information. Try opening a document of any age and doing "save as" to create a fresh copy then compare the file sizes.... (Not tried with newer .docx format yet).

Comment: @SteveBarnes Wow, that's impressive. ....my friend is using Word 2013, I don't know if that's the same....next time I mail my CV it'll be in a PDF :P (if I can)

Comment: @SteveBarnes I tried that, unfortunately "there are no previous versions of this documet." Oh well :(