# Free Software for Data Restore

Tags: data-recovery

I have a Seagate 1TB HDD.  I had around 250G of data on it.  While trying to format USB drive using Command Line, I typed that wrong Port. Instead of the USB, the HDD got formatted. I have checked using Seagate Backup Restore Software trial (paid version), it shows all the files and folders can be restored.  Is there any free alternative software that could help restore the data?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at a previous Q&A on "[File recovery software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/251/)"? I've used one of the options mention ([TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)) with success, although my scenario was slightly different from yours.

Comment: Your question does not mention what file system you were using so it's impossible to answer. Please clarify.

Comment: If Windows, try https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva