# About the proper data recovery software for deleted partitions ( merged partitions after installing windows)

Tags: gratis, open-source, data, hard-disk

One of my friend and has tried to install the new windows and merged  all the computer partitions and deleted important data from its hard drive, so we are trying to help him to recover its data.

I have seen some video about Data Recovery from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=reoveryafter%20creating%20Partitions%20) and some question like [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/251/file-recovery-software), so I want to know what is the software for recovering data after deleting, some partitions of the hard drive.

So my search results and the Software [my search on the Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=whole%20disk%20is%20formatted%20and%20all%20the%20partitions%20are%20lost%20with%20a%20fresh%20windows%20is%20installed&oq=whole%20disk%20is%20formatted%20and%20all%20the%20partitions%20are%20lost%20with%20a%20fresh%20windows%20is%20installed&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) recommended, could be seen at the below:

[EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XI4y6HnpjEg)

[Wondershare Recoverit Data Recovery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifSH7gNSvCI)

[Disk Drill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WY3KZ7vCbng)

[Data Recovery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzox85xaDBY&t=0s)

If possible, I want to have you answer your comment for introducing the proper software for recovering data in this situation.

**Update 1:**

I have updated this question and now I am trying to find some **opensource and free software** for this usage, and I found the [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/841214/any-good-open-source-file-recovery-software-for-windows), which suggests the **Teskdisk** as opensource recovery software for windows OS.

But if possible I have asked  again to have some more comment or answer.

Thanks.

Comment: "merged partitions after installing windows" HDD or SSD? If it was an SSD, forget it. You'll need to go back to your last backup. For HDD, see the linked question.

Comment: All of them are fine. But be aware if you recover exe bat scr etc.. you'll be in trouble. I'd first check disk for errors.