# Searching for Opensource data recovery software for deleted partitions ( merged partitions after installing windows)

Tags: open-source, data-recovery

I have asked one question about the the above title [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/80673/about-the-proper-data-recovery-software-for-deleted-partitions-merged-partitio?noredirect=1#comment98736_80673) and according to the comments there is some problem of using none free recommended software like said bellow:

[EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XI4y6HnpjEg)

[Wondershare Recoverit Data Recovery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifSH7gNSvCI)

[Disk Drill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WY3KZ7vCbng)

[Data Recovery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzox85xaDBY&t=0s)

So I am trying to find some **opensource and free software** for this usage, and I found the [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/841214/any-good-open-source-file-recovery-software-for-windows), which suggests the **Teskdisk** as opensource recovery software for windows OS.

But if possible I have asked  again this question to have some more comment or answer, also if is it against the rule of this forum I can merge this question to the first question as update part.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello so sa!  Yes, if you can please merge your 2 questions together, that will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: So, now I have merged two questions, and the new question is what to do with this question ( delete it or ...)?

Comment: No problem.  I'll mark it as a duplicate for you.  I added some relevant tags to your original question to try to get you more exposure.